# 500 Internal error server when I use @Query in Spring data rest 2.0.0

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am trying to upgrade an application made with Spring data rest 1.0.0 to Spring data rest 2.0.0. The problem is with a method which gives me the result of a count query. This method works fine in the first version but, when I run the second version, I get, in my browser, a 500 error. I'm not getting more error log. The log of the server is not tell me anything and the application is not throwing any exception.

This is the code of my repository:

```
public interface FilmRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository <Film,Long>{

public Page<Film> findByTituloContains(@Param("titulo") String titulo, Pageable pageable);

@Query("Select count(*) "+
        "From peliculas p inner join p.castFilm r"
        + " WHERE p.id=:id")
public Long numOfActors(@Param("id") Long id);
```

}

This is the unique method with the "@Query" annotation. The others methods are working fine. The funny thing is that I coded a JUnit to test this method and it gives me the right result without errors.

My server is a Tomcat 7.0.41. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are not getting much in the log suggests that the request may not be even reaching the controller. Try setting your log level to DEBUG and see if it even gets into Spring Data Rest code. The next step would be to just run Tomcat in debug mode and step into the code to see where the request gets rejected.